# Prove that three points lie on a semicircle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles, slope

I have three points
$A(-10,-12)$,
$B(6,18)$,
$C(-2,-14)$.
I have to prove they exist on the same semicircle. How?

If I try to draw the three points to investigate I see that I can draw a right triangle. I know you can inscribe a right triangle between three points of a semicircle, the diameter being the hypotenuse of this triangle.

So I thought I could do Pythagoras/distance formula between the points to find $AB$, $BC$, and $AC$. Then verify with Pythagoras whether $\sqrt{AC^2+BC^2}=BA$ , but for some reason this does not add up to the expected result (why not?)

So I looked up the solution and it reads:
\begin{align*}
m_{AB} &= \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A} 
= \phantom{-}\frac{18+12}{6+10} = \frac{30}{16} = \frac{15}{8} \\
m_{BC} &= \frac{y_C-y_B}{x_C-x_B} 
= \frac{-14-18}{-2-6} = \frac{-32}{-8} = 4 \\
m_{CA} &= \frac{y_A-y_C}{x_A-x_C} 
= \frac{-12+14}{-10+2} = \frac{2}{-8} = -\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

Since
$$
4 \cdot \frac{-1}{4} = -1,
$$
$BC$ is perpendicular to $CA$ (negative reciprocal) and hence $\triangle ABC$ is a right angled triangle.

Since the angle in a semicircle is a right angle it follows that $AB$ is a diameter and the points form a semicircle.

So I understand that

> $$m_{AB} = \frac{y_B- y_A}{x_B-x_A}$$

Is the gradient formula
$$
\frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}}
$$

So basically this (more efficient) solution is ignoring lengths/distances and leapfrogging lines and is going straight to prove there is a right angle (clever!)

But I wonder... why would my solution still not work?

Comment: Three points of a triangle can lie on the same semicircle if the the triangle is right or obtused angled.

Comment: $\sqrt{AC^2+BC^2}=BA$ is true, you might have made some calculation error.

Comment: You've made an arithmetic error. Your triangle has legs $(16, 30, 34)$, which is double the primitive Pythagorean triple $(8, 15, 17)$.

Comment: You are right. It was a calculation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\vec{AC}=(8,-2)$, $\vec{BC}=(-8,-32)$ and $\vec{BA}=(-16,-30)$

so we have

$$|AC|^2+|BC|^2=68+1088=1156=|BA|^2$$

---

Thus $\frac{1}{2}|BA|=17$ is the radius of the circle, centred at $(-2,3)$ and thus its equation is given by

$$(x+2)^2+(y-3)^2=17^2$$

[image]

Comment: How did you find the centre?

Comment: The centre lies halfway between the $A$ and $B$ since $|AB|$ is the diameter of the circle, so we have $C=\frac{1}{2}\left(A+B\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

For three points of a plane passes only one circumference, and this has equation:

$x^{2}+y^{2}+4x-6y-276=0$.

In fact, the coordinates of the three points satisfy the equation, that is, they make it an identity.